# Why do I get an error about the constant SODIUM_LIBRARY_VERSION not being found?

Tags: 8, composer

I'm on shared hosting, and I'm trying to install drupal 8 using composer. When I run `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:8.x-dev my_site_name_dir`, I get this error.

> constant(): Couldn't find constant SODIUM_LIBRARY_VERSION

I also tried without `recommended-project`, following instructions [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#composer-from-scratch) but the same thing happened.

`phpinfo()` suggests sodium is installed.

> [image]

I read that there may be an issue with the *libsodium* extension and the *Sodium* module as described in [Module cannot be installed using PHP > 7.0](https://www.drupal.org/project/sodium/issues/2948992), but this isn't related to core.

*Sodium* isn't mentioned anywhere as a dependency in the [requirements for Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/system-requirements/php-requirements#extensions), so I'm wondering if Composer is the issue.

What could actually have a dependency on that module? What might be the reason  it isn't finding the constant despite the fact the PHP extension seems to be installed?

Comment: Double-check that the `php` you are using to execute composer is the version that you think it is.  On a shared host I use, you have to set the PHP for the site in a web admin UI, but when you SSH in on the command line, you also have to call the correct PHP binary by alias-- this has bitten me more than once.  You could have a situation where the PHP you call from the command line is a different version than what composer calls.

Comment: @PatrickKenny good shout, but `composer -vvv` says it is running PHP 7.3.17 which is the same as the web server is showing via phpinfo().

Comment: If you run `php -m | grep sodium` from the same path you run `composer create-project`, do you see an output? Your web server and CLI PHP can be configured to use different extensions, so the version string isn't a good indicator

Comment: @Clive thanks! The output is: `libsodium`